# How to create an search using the Filter Condition as an Formula Date Field with NVAL2 Function in SuiteScript 2.0 version

Tags: javascript, search, filter, netsuite, suitescript

I want to create an custom search using Suite Script 2.0 version with the Filter Condition as an **Formula Date Field** with **NVAL2 Function**

I'm achieving this search on the UI as Saved Searches but i want create it on the Code itself.

Search Filter Created on the UI(Saved Search):

[image: Filter Condition using Formula Date field with NVAL2 Function]

**My Code:**

```
var mySearch = search.create({
    type: 'customrecord_configuration',
    columns: ['custrecord_supervisor'],
    filters: [
        [
            [
                ['custrecord_from_date', 'greaterthanorequalto', fromDate],   'AND', ['Formula Date', 'lesserthanoreqaulto', NVL2({
                    custrecord_end_date
                }, {
                    custrecord_end_date
                }, TO_DATE('01/01/2200', 'MM/DD/YYYY'))]
            ]
        ]
    ]
});
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The internal ID for a *Formula (Date)* column would be `formuladate`, and your formula value needs to be a String:

```js
[
    'formuladate', 'lesserthanoreqaulto',
    "NVL2({custrecord_end_date}, {custrecord_end_date}, TO_DATE('01/01/2200', 'MM/DD/YYYY'))"
]
```

If you use Chrome, you can also try [this Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/netsuite-search-export/gglbgdfbkaelbjpjkiepdmfaihdokglp?hl=en-GB) that lets you export UI searches directly to code.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the extension!  I didn't know about it.  Seems like it could come in handy on various occasions

Comment: It is very handy. Be aware that you have to actually save the search before the extension will generate code for it; a lot of people seem to miss that part of the instructions.